# Rails - ordering loops from acts_as_follower gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I implemented this gem and everything works great, but when I list all of the items my user is following through "user.all_following" it lists it in descending order, from the most oldest to the most recent followed being the last item listed. Im trying to figure out how to reverse this and make the most recent followings displayed first and later following under it. Thanks.

```
<% allfollows = @user.all_follows %>
<% allfollows.each do |item| %>
....
<& end &>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is pass `order` option to your `all_follows` method call.
For example:

`@user.all_follows(order: "follows.id DESC")`

By the way, currently you are getting records in `ascending`(most oldest to the most recent) order and NOT `descending`(most recent to most oldest).

Comment: hey when I try this, for some reason my site crashes and returns this to me: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: desc: SELECT "follows".* FROM "follows"  WHERE "follows"."follower_id" = 15 AND "follows"."follower_type" = 'User' AND "follows"."blocked" = 'f' ORDER BY desc

Comment: hey thanks, it doesnt give me an error now but for some reason im still getting the same order...

Comment: i also tried replacing follower_id with followable_id but it outputs nonsense

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is given in the README of the gem: https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower

The following methods take an optional hash parameter of ActiveRecord options (:limit, :order, etc…)

```
follows_by_type, all_follows, all_following, following_by_type
```

OR

```
Follow.descending # returns all records in a descending order based on created_at datetime
```

So you can basically filter by anything you wish. I haven't ever used this gem, but this would make most sense to me.

Comment: could you explain to me how I would implement this? I have updated my question with my code. Thanks

Comment: I would load the followers in the controller, rather than the view. So basically in the action which requires you to list all the followers I would go for: @followers = user.all_following(order: "created_at desc"). The created at perhaps needs to be replaced with whatever is used to keep a record whenever the follow has been placed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also method present i.e `descending`

Example:-

```
@user.follows.descending
```

This gives you a descending order of records.

Thanks.